# Copied a folder from Windows to Ubuntu, have no permissions

Tags: permissions

I took a web project from my Window's disk and put it under /var/www.

localhost (my web server) doesn't recognize it because of permissions.

What do I need to run on the folder so that apache can read/write to it?

I tried recursive chmod, didn't work.

Comment: You also changed the owner of the files right?

Answer (score 0):

from command line go to /var/www and type:

```
ls -lhat
```

check the ownership of your files. The command above should show you the user/group for your index file. Is it the same as the files you copied over?

If you installed a web server from a repository, the user/group is likely www-data:www-data or nginx:nginx (depending on your web server). Ensure that the files you copied over have the proper ownership. You can change the ownership by:

```
chown <user>:<group> files
```

Example:
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/folder